Moodle 4.1.6 not sending emails for new forum posts
I know there are many posts on this topic but none of the solutions work for me. Indeed, my symptoms are slightly different from other cases I have seen. I'm hoping someone has some insights that can help.
First, the situation: I have access to a Moodle admin account (for my org) to fix this problem. I do not, however, have access to the machine (I think it is a VPS but I'm not sure) nor the underlying database. So, my options are limited. The people who do control the machine are either unwilling or unable to solve this, as it does not really impact them. However, as a teacher, it impacts me and my students significantly.
This is a version 4.1.6 instance of Moodle. Overall it seems to run fine. I setup the outgoing email settings just like I had on previous instances of Moodle. When I test send an email, the email gets sent, and it gets received. So far, so good.
The forums, including the Announcements forum, never seem to send an email for new posts (or replies), even though they are set to auto-subscribe (I believe Announcements is force subscribe).
Here's one funny thing, I do get regular emails from the server, telling me things like "Courses with start dates in the next week have been identified as having no teacher or student enrolments." So, again, I am sure the email settings (both on Moodle and in Gmail) are configured correctly.
When I login to Gmail, for the outbound email account Moodle is configured to use, there are messages in the Sent folder, but not for forums. For example, I see some students are getting password reset emails. I see teachers getting insight emails like "Students at risk."
Still, when I create an announcement, whether normal or "send without delay" nothing gets sent. It is not just for me. There are no sent items from forums in the sent folder.
I have set it up so I can run cron via the web, to ensure that is not the problem. I keep running it, every five minutes or so as part of my testing. Still, none of these emails are being sent.
Am I missing something here? I've been trying to sort this problem out for many hours over many days, but never finding any happiness.
I sure would appreciate if anyone has any insights.
